# How to display an image along with audio in html/html5?

Tags: html, audio, html5-audio

I want to display an image with an audio attachment like an mp3 file. What's the best way to make this work in html5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something as simple as this?

```
<img src="some_image.jpg" />
<audio controls
   src="some_audio.mp3">
   Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
</audio>
```

This will display whatever image with an audio track underneath. If you'd like some sort of dynamic interaction with the img+audio you will need to use javascript. I can give an example if that's the case.

Comment: This links to the audio file and makes it clickable to play. I was looking for something which can make the audio file clickable to play below the image, not as a link on the image. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: In that case you should use the <audio> element. Would you like the audio to only appear after you've interacted with the image?I'll update my answer but I'm still not fully clear as to the exact intended behaviour.

Comment: The intention was to have an audio file describing the object in the image. This seems to be a reasonable way to achieve it using html.